# Aura:Iteration Tag Not Working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, iteration

I am trying to display information from the users object, but I cannot get the components to cooperate. Code is below:

apex:

```
public with sharing class LACC_ObjController {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<User> getMyObjects() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM User];
  }
}
```

cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="LACC_ObjController">
  <aura:attribute name="MyObjects" type="User[]" />
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.MyObjects}" var="obj">
            {!obj.Id}
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

and js:

```
({
  getMyObjects: function(cmp){
    var action = cmp.get("c.getMyObjects");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set("v.myObjects", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

The when I view the page, nothing shows up. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is calling the `getMyObjects` method in your client-side javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the DoInit handler.  Rename your javascript from "getMyObjects" to "doInit."

Component:

```
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

Controller:

```
({
  doInit: function(cmp){
    var action = cmp.get("c.getMyObjects");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set("v.MyObjects", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

As a best practice, you should not name your client side functions the same as your apex controller. If you do, you could end up recursively calling the controller which will throw a big error.

Please also note that javascript is case sensitive.  Your set of "MyObjects" was spelled as "myObjects" and would have thrown an error.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, however I still have nothing showing up on screen. Should the <aura:handler> line be the first line in the component file?

Comment: yes, but you also need to make sure the 'MyObjects' matches case. this answer corrected the case of it, but your example code shows a mismatch between the attribute definition and the controller code.